# Hello, Why can't I use two return statements in react.js components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two functions MissedGoal and MadeGoal using the condition I want to the functions to be displayed alternatively according to the Boolean value (True, false). When I change the prop value in index.js from true is displays MadeGoal when I change prop value to false is displays MissedGoal
Here is my Code Cond.js

```
import React from 'react'

function MissedGoal() {
 return <h1>Missed!</h1>
}
function MadeGoal() {
 return <h1>Goal!</h1>
}

function Cond(props) {
 const isGoal = props.isGoal;
 if (isGoal) {
  return <MadeGoal />;
 }
  return <MadeGoal />;
  return (
    <div>
     {isGoal}</div>
  )
}

export default Cond
```

It rendered below by index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import Jsx from './Jsx'
import Tools from './Tools';
import Trick from './Trick';
import Foot from './Foot';
import Cond from './Cond';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
    <Jsx />
    <Tools name="Ishmo" tool="Adobe"/>
    <Trick />
    <Foot />
    <Cond isGoal= {true}/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Wrap both elements/components in a fragment component

Comment: I guess that you need a basic programming tutorial at this point. It will help you understand a lot what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return this

```
  return (
   <>
   <MadeGoal />
    <div>
     {isGoal}
    </div>
   </>
  )
```

The <> (can change to <React.Fragment> for key) is called react fragment
[Read here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 1):

The Third return in function Cond is redundant . Control will never reach there.
Control goes out of the block after encountering a return statement

Comment: what should I use instead of return that will render the functions?

Comment: Do it like return (<>  <Component1 /> <Component2 /> </>)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** **React components are just functions**, so when we return multiple elements at the same level, we are effectively using multiple return statements at the same level of a function.

**When JavaScript reaches a return statement, the function will stop executing.**

If the function was invoked from a statement, JavaScript will "return" to execute the code after the invoking statement.

Functions often compute a return value. The return value is "returned" back to the "caller":

If you return the third statement you can use condition (if, else if, else).`

```
import React from 'react'


function MissedGoal() {
  return <h1>Missed!</h1>
}

function MadeGoal() {
  return <h1>Goal!</h1>
}


function Cond(props) {

  const isGoal = props.isGoal;

  if (isGoal) {
    return <MadeGoal />
  } else if (isGoal == false) {
    return <MissedGoal />
  } else {
    return <div>Please add your message here</div>
  }
}

export default Cond;
```

`

Answer (score -2):

```
 const isGoal = props.isGoal;
 if (isGoal) {
  return <MadeGoal />;
 }
  return <MadeGoal />; // change it to MissedGoal component
  return (
    <div>
     {isGoal}</div>
  )
}
```

here both times you are returning

and after returning a component you cant return it again if you returned me my pen then without again taking it how can you again give me

**so you cant return a component 2 times because the code is not reachable**

Comment: Thank you @Veer-Khatri.  I fixed missedGoal component. So what should I do to display the other components

Comment: @AYEBAZIBWE you can add both return values in one like  ```return( <madeGoal /> <div>{isGoal}<div/>)```